# Reference request for selfdecomposable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, probability-distributions

In a probability theorem course I'm attending to we are covering stable, infinitely divisible and self-decomposable variables. I am only aware of the formal definitions like: $X$ is self-decomposable iff for every $c \in [0,1]$ there exist $X_c$ (independent of $X$) such that $X = cX + X_c$, where the equality is meant as "in distribution".

However with this knowledge I am unable to solve the exercises/problems that I am supposed to solve. Here is one of them: find the Levy's spectral measure of Laplace distribution. Therefore I ask:

What is the best source to learn about self-decomposable variables, Kolmogorov or Levy-Khintchine formulas and so on? I must add that I have never encountered a stochastic process in the past if it does matter.

Comment: Sato's book (Levy processes and infinitely divisble distribution) discusses selfdecomposable random variables.